# How do you route to secondary interface on the same physical port?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

INTERNET<->(wan)BRIDGED_DEVICE(lan)<->ETH_ROUTER<->LAN

*Problem:*
Need to access web server on BRIDGED_DEVICE's LAN from INTERNET via ROUTER (BRIDGED_DEVICE web server cannot be accessed form INTERNET since it has no Public management IP).

*Attempt:*
Create a secondary/alias WAN Interface on ETH_ROUTER (e.g Primary: eth0.1 (for internet access) and Secondary: eth0.2 (for accessing web server on BRIDGED_DEVICE),  (No VLANs).

- eth0.1 has a public IP;
- eth0.2 has a static private IP in the BRIDGED_DEVICE's subnet (e.g 10.0.X.Y).

Iptables on ETH_ROUTER: Added a port forward (DNAT) from eth0.1 to eth0.2:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.X.Y
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0.2 -s 10.0.X.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Stateful firewall w/ overall drop policy on FORWARD chain, hence:

```
 iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0.1 -d 10.0.X.Y -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Can ping from ETH_ROUTER to BRIDGED_DEVICE but unable to reach the web server from Internet. I see packet cont increasing for the DNAT rule but not sure where it disappears in the ETH_ROUTER after that.

ETH_ROUTER is the only device that can be configured to achieve this.

If familiar with this scenario, please suggest what I may be missing or doing wrong here or suggest techniques to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Check default gateway on bridged device and forwarding rule from bridged device to internet also. If you don't care about internet source ip you can add a source nat from router to bridged device.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I cannot configure the bridged device, have to do everything on ETH_ROUTER. Thanks.

Comment: Well, so you have to dnat in first place to redirect packet to brdged device and than snat or masquerade packet to let bridged device believe that them comes from router.